# How change video background-image in owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Now class .owl-video-tn has got an inline style, for example: background-image: url(//img.youtube.com/vi/EF_kj2ojZaE/hqdefault.jpg). But I need the ability to embed my photos to preview video? How to realize this possibility?

https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/WKBjOa

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    video:true,
    lazyLoad:false,
    center:true,
    responsive:{
        480:{
            items:2
        },
        600:{
            items:4
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override css with your image like this

```
.owl-video-tn {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/600x400') !important;
}
```

if you want to target specific image you could use e.g `:nth-child` to target the specific video element by specifiing index

like this:

```
.owl-item:nth-child(5) .owl-video-tn {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/600x400') !important;
}
```

Comment: I want to change the pictures from the admin panel later. Therefore, the option through the CSS is not suitable for me.

Comment: You haven't specified that in your question. you can just use jQuery for that $('yourClass').css('background', 'url('+ imageUrl +')';